# Trimming whitespace from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, filter, replace

I realize there are quite a number of questions on this but I have yet to find a solution suitable for my situation. I know of string.trim() and it has no effect. After researching online and uncovering a world of hate for string.trim() I realize that the whitespace character I am trying to remove must be out of the range .trim() caters for.

I am using some regex, which I do not fully understand, to strip the string of any special characters excluding '=' and ',' and all whitespace EXCEPT if it is immediately after the ','.

However, I now want to completely remove all whitespace from the string. Any ideas of how to edit the regex I am using to accomplish this would be appreciated. Again, what I want is '=' and ',' along with digits and letters to remain. All whitespace and other special characters should be removed.

Here's the code so far:

```
if (argsToBeFiltered != null) {
            // Remove all whitespace and chars apart from = and ,
            String filteredArgs = argsToBeFiltered.replaceAll(
                    "[^=,\\da-zA-Z\\s]|(?<!,)\\s", "");
            return filteredArgs;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time to learn a regular expression!

See [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and various regular expression tutorials such as [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

```
[^=,\\da-zA-Z\\s]
```

That part says match NOT (^) the characters: `=`, `,`, digits (\d), A-Z (A-Z) or *whitespace* (\s). However, you likely want it to match spaces now (as there is no second after-comma part to match them). So:

```
argsToBeFiltered.replaceAll("[^=,\\da-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: That's not quite right.  `\\s` (or `\s` after the String escaping) is more than just spaces, but also includes vertical and horizontal tabs, carriage return/line feed, etc...

Comment: @R. Bemrose Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
if (argsToBeFiltered != null) {
            // Remove all whitespace and chars apart from = and ,
            String filteredArgs = argsToBeFiltered.replaceAll(
                    "\\w+");
            return filteredArgs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks CoolBeans - pst nailed it for me though. Cheers for the interest!